# How to resize an image like facebook cover

Tags: php, facebook, gd

What basically I am trying to do is to create a cover page for my personal website, just like facebook. Basically I am after the same layout of the cover as on facebook, so that user can get the same result while using the same cover on my site as well as on facebook.

The part I am stucked at is the "Drag image to position cover" thing. 
The Facebook uses some algorithm to convert the cover image size to something different during dragging thing. For example, if the original image dimensions are 920x720, the dimensions of same image while it is on facebook setting-cover page(drag image to position cover thing), the dimensions of the image are 851x638.

I just wanted to know what algorithm facebook uses to set the image dimensions(from 720 to 638)

**NOTE: The cover has to be the pixel perfect**

I know that the cover dimension of facebook is 851x315, so here is what I am doing:

```
    //$x =  X origin cordinate variable obtained by dragging image 
    //$y =  Y origin cordinate variable obtained by dragging image 
    list($k, $l) = getimagesize($src); // $src == image source 
    //$w = Needs to be calculated
    //$h = Needs to be calculated 
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( 854,316 );
    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$x,$y,$w,$h,$k,$l);
    imagejpeg($dst_r,$src,$jpeg_quality);
    $img_name = writeToImage($src, $des); //writeToImage() is just a demo function created by me to do some other things with them which do not affect this part of code

    echo $img_name;
```

I need to figure out how facebook calculates the new dimension of the image from previous one. Is it dependent of the actual(original) size of the image or is it dependent on some other factors?

Comment: You wrote 851x638. Did you mean 815x638?

Comment: @Herbert: No. I meant 851x638 only. I am quite sure about what I am writing about pixels in this situation. So there is no chance of errors in dimensions/pixels

Comment: jquery drag events may help you. I overcome this problem by messing aroung Jcrop events.  [Jcrop Overview](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)

Comment: The reason I asked is because 920x720 has the same aspect ratio as 815x638. If facebook changes it to 851, then either it's stretching it horizontally or, there would be blank bars on either side of the image.

Comment: The question is not about how can I use the drag/Crop. Question is about getting the `scaled` value of the image, for which the facebook has quite good algorithm and which I wanted to know. I have to resize the image before getting it functional for drag/drop

Comment: in that case i guess you should do some reversing, get your calculator, try some more pictures and calculate the ratio.

Comment: It's not an ingenious algorithm. It's a simple scale factor.

Comment: @Herbert: From what I think, The facebook stretches/fits the whole image to a maximum width of 851px, because it is what I am getting with many of other images with different dimensions. But for the height, there is some algorithm, for the reason that the constant aspect ratio(if it uses) would give out nearly same height as though

Comment: If you scale 920x720 down to 851px wide, you get 666px tall. Since you measured 638px tall, that's only a difference of 28px. So either it's cropping off 28 pixels or shrinking the height. When you compare the original image to the one that's 851x638, what differences do you notice?

Comment: one thing for sure that the facebook cover is not cropped. I think it is displayed by the use of clip: rect of CSS.

Comment: Ok got it. I ran few more tests and got this simple result:
`960/720 = 1.33333;` and 
  `851/1.3333 = 638`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulas for scaling images are quite simple.

```
$aspect_ratio = $original_width / $original_height;

$new_width = $new_height * $aspect_ratio;
```

or

```
$new_height = $new_width / $aspect_ratio;
```